# Django 1.11 How to display template variable from within HTML saved in model for CMS Site

Tags: html, django, templates, view, models

Within a template, I need to render a {{ variable }} from HTML content saved in a model instance.

Below are the stripped down parts of the code.

**page.html**

```
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <styles, links, etc.>
    <title>{{ object.title }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>{{ object.html_content }}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Model**

```
class Page(models.Model):

  title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  html_content = models.TextField()
```

**GlobalMixin**

```
# Used site wide for Global information.

class GlobalMixin(object):

  def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(GlobalMixin, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['variable'] = "A Global piece of information"
    return context
```

**View**

```
from .mixins import GlobalMixin
from .models import Page

PageView(GlobalMixin, generic.DetailView):

  model = Page
  template_name = "my_app/page.html"

  def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(PageView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    return context
```

**Admin & HTML Content Field**
I then enter admin, add new Page, enter my HTML content into html_content Field "Html Content" as per the following example.

```
<p>This is {{ variable }} that I need to display within my rendered page!</p>
```

Then **SAVE**.

**BROWSER RESULTS**

```
This is {{ variable }} that I need to display within my loaded page!
```

I know there is Django Flat Pages, but it doesn't look like it works for me as I require Global variables in my templates that flat pages doesn't offer.

The template is being rendered directly with the models content without looking at it. 
I think I need to process the html_content field in the view and then add the required context variables to the context returned or save a temporary template file, append the html_content into the file, then render it.

How do I do make this work?
Is there a Django packaged interface that I can use to process the template from within my view?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. Here's the code if anyone else comes across this or has a better way, please share.

Change View type to TemplateView, use slug in url to get model instance, use django.template.engines to convert the string to a template object then render the template object and return it in the context.

**page.html**

```
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <styles, links, etc.>
    <title>{{ object.title }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- <div>{{ object.html_content }}</div> -->
    <div>{{ html_content }}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from .mixins import GlobalMixin
from .models import Page

# NEW
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.template import engines

PageView(GlobalMixin, TemplateView):  # generic.DetailView

  # model = Page
  template_name = "my_app/page.html"

  def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(PageView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

    # NEW
    context['object']  = get_object_or_404(Page, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
    t = engines['django'].from_string(context['object'].html_content)
    context['html_content'] = t.render(context=context, request=None)
    return context
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought you could use custom filter like below.

file path

- `yourapp/templatetags/__init__.py`
- `yourapp/templatetags/filters.py`

filters.py

```
from django import template
import re

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name="change_global_variable")
def change_global_variable(value):
    return re.sub(r'\{\{(.*)\}\}', 'A global piece', value)
```

template

```
{% load static %}
{% load filters %} //filters.py//
<html>
  <head>
    <styles, links, etc.>
    <title>{{ object.title }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>{{ object.html_content | change_global_variable}}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes that would work but will require loading the Global Variables twice in my application and add to processing time. It would load Globals once in the view Mixin for all other fields required in the template, then again in the processing of the template via filter. I like your thinking though.

Comment: then, I would rather process it with javascripts.